# Nestjs websocket gateway with SSL is not working

Tags: typescript, ssl, websocket, nestjs

I have added SSL support for my [nest.js](https://nestjs.com/) server according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59084627/6687927):

```
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('certs/localhost.key', 'utf8');
  const certificate = fs.readFileSync('certs/localhost.cert', 'utf8');
  const httpsOptions = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

  const server = express();
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server));
  await app.init();

  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });

  if (process.env.DEV) {
    https.createServer(httpsOptions, server).listen(3006);
    console.log('Running in DEV mode using secure HTTPS');
  } else {
    http.createServer(server).listen(3006);
  }
```

Everything works fine, I can access using HTTPS.

Now there is my websocket gateway I have created which worked fine when I was on HTTP:

```
const options = {
    cors: {
        origin: true,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true,
    }
}
@WebSocketGateway(3007, options)
export class SessionWebsocket {

    @WebSocketServer()
    private server: Server;
    ...... And more irrelevant code.
}
```

Whenever I try to access the websocket server over HTTPS I get the following errors in network:

[image]

Is there anything I need to change in the gateway in order to make it work? [The page explaining about the gateways interface](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways) does not state anything about SSL or TLS.

**EDIT:**

The port the nestjs server runs at is 3006 and the port of the websocket server is 3007, you can't run two same ports.

The way I connect to the websocket:

```
export const SESSION_SOCKET_URL = '//localhost:3007';

this.sessionClient.connect(sessionId, SESSION_SOCKET_URL);

  public connect(sessionId: string, socketConnectionString: string) {
    const options = {
      transportOptions: {
        polling: {
          extraHeaders: { // This is unrelated to the question, just custom headers, shouldn't affect my issue
            'sessionId': sessionId // If undefined, server will generate and send a notify event
          }
        }
      },
    }

    this.socketClient = io(socketConnectionString, options).connect();

    this.socketClient.on('connect', () => {
      this.notifyOnConnected.next({
        clientId: this.socketClient.id
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is few potential issues, the way how you create cert, the domain, the protocol that you're using to connect to the server over socket, port that you're listening (80 when your server runs on PORT || 3006), needs more clarification, how you connect etc

Comment: The certificate was created with openssl, It's the same certificate as I use in other dev projects and it works fine with REST calls, the domain is a custom domain I set in windows HOSTS file which redirects to localhost, Ill update my question

Comment: @benberizovsky, were you able to figure out a solution? I am also facing the same issue, I have added certificates to my nest server. I can even hit the REST API using https. But, I cannot use wss:// when I am trying to connect through socket.

Comment: @MohamedImran Try using the answer I posted, it solved my issue. Create an inheritance for IoAdapter like I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NestJS Gateway by default uses an `AbstractWsAdapter`, not certainly sure what Adapter implements it by default.

However, I couldn't find a way to get control over the server creation without a custom adapter, and I didn't want to start another server dedicated for the websocket, but instead use the http server that is used for nest rest API.

So what I did to solve this issue is, first implement the HTTPS server in the place you bootstrap your nestjs application:

```
async function bootstrap() {

    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('certs/localhost.key', 'utf8');
    const certificate = fs.readFileSync('certs/localhost.cert', 'utf8');
    const httpsOptions = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

    const server = express();
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server));

    const httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions);
    app.useWebSocketAdapter(new ExtendedSocketIoAdapter(httpsServer));

    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.enableCors({
        origin: true,
        methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
        credentials: true,
    });

    await app.init();

    httpsServer.listen(3006);
}
```

Basically here you initialize an HTTPS server, and as you see I created my own adapter which extends `IoAdapter` for socket.io:

```
export class ExtendedSocketIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
    protected ioServer: io.Server;

    constructor(protected server: https.Server) {
        super();

        const options = {
            cors: {
                origin: true,
                methods: ["GET", "POST"],
                credentials: true,
            }
        }

        this.ioServer = new io.Server(server, options);
    }

    create (port: number) {
        console.log('websocket gateway port argument is ignored by ExtendedSocketIoAdapter, use the same port of http instead')
        return this.ioServer
    }
}
```

So instead of creating a new https server, you basically create a new instace of IoServer and passing in the HTTPS server you created when you initialized your nest application.

The parameters in the `@WebSocketGateway({port, options)` at this point are ignored, so at this point it can be empty -> `@WebSocketGateway()`

And now the websocket server will run on top of the HTTPS server.

This solved my issue.

Comment: with your aproach, wss connection works. by my regular nestjs https  REST request now keeps hanging. Any idea on this?